# Different behavior when looping through a list of variables

Tags: templating

I apologize for the seemingly vague title, but I honestly don't know the best way to state this problem succinctly!

This is within the context of a particular section's entry template.

**What I want to happen:**

I want to loop through a list of variables that call different Entry elementCriteriaModels and for each iteration of this loop I want to get the section's handle.

**How I tried to make it happen:**

*Get related entries from a number of different sections*

```
{% set towns = craft.entries.section('towns').relatedTo(county) %}
{% set citizens = craft.entries.section('inductees').relatedTo(county) %}
{% set events = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo(county) %}
```

*Make a list of those elementCriteriaModel objects*

```
{% set arrayOfSections = [
    towns,
    citizens,
    events
] %}
```

*Loop through that list and try to get the section handle of whatever the first entry is of each section*

```
{% for section in arrayOfSections %}
    {% set sectionHandle = section.first().getSection() %}
    {{ sectionHandle }}
```

**What actually happens**

I get the following error: "Impossible to invoke a method ("getSection") on a null variable."

When I try to do the same thing on an object that is outside of that `arrayOfSections` list, it works just fine!

**Why am I even trying to do this??**

There is a huge part of this template that repeats itself over and over. If I can successfully loop through these related sections in this way that problem will be fixed. I've thought about turning this into a macro, but I'd still have to call this macro nearly half a dozen times and manually feed in the desired section each time...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `section.first()` returns an element. The error occurs because `section.first()` is `null` => no element was found with your criteria. And the value `null` has no function `getSection`.

However - keep in mind your `sectionHandle` variable is not the handle of the section, but the `SectionModel`thus your code as it is currently is not really performant